# ERROR YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Asked to remove non-existent executor 21

Tags: configuration, apache-spark

When I first run

```
lines = sc.textFile(os.path.join(folder_name),100)
```

and then

```
parsed_lines=lines.map(lambda line: parse_line(line, ["udid"])).persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK).groupByKey(1000).take(10)
```

I get the following error:

```
...
ERROR YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Asked to remove non-existent executor 21
...
WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.1 in stage 11.7 (TID 1151, <machine name>): FetchFailed(null, shuffleId=0, mapId=-1, reduceId=896, message=
org.apache.spark.shuffle.MetadataFetchFailedException: Missing an output location for shuffle 0
```

I tried to change the following parameters as well as the number of splits in groupbykey and number of partitions in the textFile function.

```
conf.set("spark.cores.max", "128")
conf.set("spark.akka.frameSize", "1024")
conf.set("spark.executor.memory", "6G")
conf.set("spark.shuffle.file.buffer.kb", "100")
```

I am not sure how to decide on these parameters based on the workers' capacities, the input size and the transformations that I will apply.

Comment: Did you ever solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I received the same error. I solved the problem by reducing the number of executors I was requesting in my spark-defaults.conf.

Say it was originally:

```
spark.executor.instances 7
```

I switched it to read:

```
spark.executor.instances 4
```

I didn't change anything else and was able to avoid the error.